# Error on Debugging docker-compose on VS2019

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose, dockerfile, microservices

I have following docker file and docker-compose, it's build and created container images fine through CLI without any problem, however when I try to build it through VS2019 for debugging purpose, it gives an error and I tried to rebuild the project to check where it goes wrong but I could not figure it out. I hope someone point me to the right direction for troubleshooting:-

Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy necessary files and restore as distinct layer
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000
HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=3s --retries=1 CMD curl --silent --fail http://localhost:5000/hc || exit 1

# Start
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "VehicleManagementAPI.dll"]
```

Docker-compose file:

```
services:
  vehiclemanagementapi:
    image: urgen/vehiclemanagementapi:1.0
    build: src/VehiclemanagementAPI
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - sqlserver
    ports:
      - "5000"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
```

It is not a particular project has a issue building/compiling docker-compose file rather it happens with all of the projects. As I said it works fine through CLI without any problem, but there has a issue with one particular project, which I wanted to debug in VS2019.

All of the projects build/work fine without dockerize, which means my projects is Okay but issue is with docker-compose or docker file.

Error :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CTC1000 (Line: 45, Col: 12, Idx: 954) - (Line: 45, Col: 36, Idx: 978): Exception during deserialization docker-compose  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets    304
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the problem by making changes in following line in docker-compose file, however I am confused why VS 2019 failed to build the project where it works fine in CLI mode, therefore my understanding is if it has a issue with the docker-compose file structure it would not have been build in CLI mode at the first place:-

```
build: src/VehicleManagementAPI  to  build: .
```

Even the error does not tell anything about the problem, error seems pointless/useless for troubleshooting.